# How to keep the width of navbar the same and make it align center

Tags: html, css, navbar

[image](the nav bar originally look like this)I am making a website, I have used bootstrap to create a navbar, if i wish to keep the width of navbar the same as before, how can i align the whole navbar center?? I have tried align center and text-center but they are not working ...

```
<div class="container-fluid menu">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light my-navbar">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="./assets/logo.png"  alt="" loading="lazy">
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Eastern Europe
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Croatia</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Crezh</a>
                </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

this is my HTML code

```
/*menu bar style*/
.menu{
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    color: black;
}

.my-navbar{

    position: absolute;
    z-index:999;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 10vh;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    background-color: white;
    top:20px;
    box-shadow:0px 4px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    z-index:999;
}
.navbar-brand img{
    position: relative;
    width: 10vw;
    height: 15vh;
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
}
```

this is my css code

Comment: How does the navbar look like before?

Comment: Try using <center></center> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override the css like that target the container `.container-fluid.menu {
    display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
}`

```css
.container-fluid.menu {
    display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
}
/*menu bar style*/
.menu{
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    color: black;
}

.my-navbar{

    position: absolute;
    z-index:999;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 10vh;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    background-color: white;
    top:20px;
    box-shadow:0px 4px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    z-index:999;
}
.navbar-brand img{
    position: relative;
    width: 10vw;
    height: 15vh;
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid menu">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light my-navbar">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/14/12/59/iceland-1979445_960_720.jpg"  alt="" loading="lazy">
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Eastern Europe
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Croatia</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Crezh</a>
                </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding "d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" classes to the nav element.

Comment: What if when you add those classes to the parent div with the classes "container-fluid menu" ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mx-auto` to the `<nav>`

```
<!-- Add mx-auto -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light my-navbar mx-auto">
```

```css
/*menu bar style*/

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
}

.my-navbar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 10vh;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  position: relative;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 15vh;
  margin: 0;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid menu">
  <!-- Add mx-auto -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light my-navbar mx-auto">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="./assets/logo.png" alt="" loading="lazy">
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Eastern Europe
                </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Croatia</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Crezh</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```